# paddingTop seems to be acting randomly

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add an icon for my app prototype by using this styling:

```
swordIcon:{
    position: "absolute",
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    paddingTop: "42%"
}
```

However, it's position is inconsistent and sometimes random. Screenshots will represent that:

[image: First behaviour]

[image: Second behaviour]

I think one time it was also something inbetween.

Why is it happening? Here's styling of the parent element if that's helpful:

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    borderColor: "red",
    borderWidth: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingTop: "5%",
    flexDirection: "column"
},
```

Comment: Try to use inspector from the debug menu, see maybe it helps you find the problem!

Comment: where is your position relative?